# Serverless - Packaged functions include other functions

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Having trouble with lambda package sizes, and not finding any working solutions.
I looked at the packages to see why a function that literally only returns the event would be 67,175 KB zipped and saw it also contains *all the other functions*.  **Why??**

I took away the `package: individually: true` and it makes the entire bundle 67,161 KB and I still get a too-large error message on function2.  What else can I do to reduce the packaging of these functions?

```
My_application
|-function1.py
|-function2.py
|-reallySmallFunction.py
|-sharedUtility.py
|-requirements.txt
|-serverless.yml
|-.serverless
|--function1.zip
|--function2.zip
|--reallySmallFunction.zip
|---function1.py
|---function2.py
|---reallySmallFunction.py
|---sharedUtility.py
```

serverless.yml -

```
> service: My_application
> 
> provider:   
>   name: aws   
>   runtime: python3.8
>   stage: dev
>   region: us-east-1
>   versionFunctions: false
>   apiName: Foo
>   timeout: 10

> package:   
>   individually: true
>   patterns:
>     - "!.cache/**"
>     - "!.pytest_cache/**"
>     - "!.env/**"
>     - "!env/*"
>     - "!venv/*"
>     - "!.venv/**"
>     - "!.git/**"
>     - "!.serverless/**"
>     - "!node_modules/**"
>     - "!unit_tests/**"
>     - "!integration_tests/**"
>     - "!README.md"
>     - "!package.json"
>     - "!package-lock.json"

> functions:   
>   function1:
>     handler: function1.function1
>     iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
>     iamRoleStatements: # as needed
>     timeout: 20
> 
>   function2:
>     handler: function2.function2
>     iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
>     iamRoleStatements: # as needed
>     timeout: 20
> 
>   reallySmallFunction:
>     handler: reallySmallFunction.reallySmallFunction
>     iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
>     iamRoleStatements:
>     timeout: 20
> 
> plugins:
>   - serverless-python-requirements
>   - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
>   - serverless-prune-versions
> 
> custom:   
>   pythonRequirements:
>     zip: false
>     slim: true
>     noDeploy:
>       - pytest
>   prune:
>     automatic: true
>     includeLayers: true
>     number: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The Serverless Framework doesn't know which functions in a stack require which dependencies unless you explicitly declare it. Serverless doesn't perform any bundling/treeshaking, doesn't create an abstract syntax tree, or do any kind of compiling of your function code.

By default it creates one bundle per stack and uploads it to each function. You can also package individually, and then *each function* can declare its own include/exclude packaging configuration.

This is covered in the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging), and some strategies to handle this have been [discussed](https://forum.serverless.com/t/is-this-expected-behavior-for-individually-packing-functions/330/4) on the forum.

I'd suggest specifically including or excluding dependencies in your `verySmallFunction`.

You may also consider separating these functions into different stacks entirely. This won't cost additional money, as AWS does not price based on number of Lambda functions deployed nor on the number of CloudFormation Stacks.

Comment: I adjusted the `package` to both `patterns: "!**/*" ` and also `exclude: "**/*"`, and both return `Error: No file matches include/exclude patterns`
Regarding your second suggestion of using separate stacks - You mean each function having it's own yml file?  Does that make it messy, in terms of shared resources, like Cognito and API URLs?

Comment: `package` can live under both the top level block AND an individual function. So my suggestion is to specify `package` separately for each function.

Also yes, separate yaml files. You can create and share resources with CloudFormation Outputs, which is designed to accomplish exactly this.

Comment: No.  I swear, I have tried every iteration.
When I'm able to get the file small enough and containing only the needed files, I get an error when calling the lambda - `"errorMessage": "Handler 'verySmallFunction' missing on module 'verySmallFunction'"` or `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'verySmallFunction.verySmallFunction': attempted relative import beyond top-level package'`

Comment: In that case, your code is importing from above it's root directory (which won't work).

Did you inspect the contents of the zip file for the verySmallFunction? It's in the `.serverless` directory. You can unzip it and ask Node to load it.